# Passing Params to Lambda Proxy Function with apigClient.js

Tags: lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function that is connected to an endpoint is API Gateway using Lambda Proxy Integration.  The endpoint is:

https://exmaple.com/fscms/dev/webhooks/{updateshipping+}

I am trying to call this endpoint using the Javascript SDK provided by API Gateway (apigClient.js) but for the life of me cannot figure out how to set the params to get it to work.  Here is the error I am getting:

```
OPTIONS https://example.com/fscms/dev/webhooks/ 403 (Forbidden)

xhrAdapter @ axios.standalone.js:747
(anonymous) @ axios.standalone.js:516
dispatchRequest @ axios.standalone.js:512
/#/orders/list:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://example.com/fscms/dev/webhooks/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://dev.example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

I can call this endpoint all day with Postman and have no issues so I know it is setup correctly and working.  It looks as though I need to do something to get apigClient.js to append "updateshipping" to the end of the endpoint it is calling, but I cannot figure this out and no amount of Googling is giving me any hints.

Here is my code for calling the endpoint:

```
    var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient();

    var params = {};
    var body = update;
    var additional_params = {};

    apigClient.webhooksUpdateshippingPost(params, body, additional_params)

    .then(function(result) {

        // This will grab error messages not generated by our server code.
        if (result.data.errorMessage) {
            $scope.shipping_info.error = result.data.errorMessage;
        }

        if(result.data.code === 0) {
            console.log(result.data.message);
        }
        else {
            $scope.shipping_info.error = result.data.message;
        }
    })

    .catch(function(result){
        $scope.shipping_info.error = result.data.message;
    }); 
};
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a known limitation with the current SDKs generated by API Gateway - they do not support invoking methods using the {proxy+}/ANY method features.

Adding support is on our backlog. Although we can't commit to any timelines, we can update this post with more information when it's been released.

Comment: Just to make sure I did not set this up right.  The endpoint in API Gateway I setup as {updateshipping+} but I did not use "ANY" as the verb.  I used "POST" only.  Is this the correct way to set this up, and would it make any difference to SDK support?

Comment: Your setup sounds fine to me. The limitation I described does apply to the {greedy_resource_path+} scenario as well, unfortunately.